# Marquee in Textview with Dynamic data android

Tags: android, textview, marquee

> I am trying to use `marquee` in `TextView` which is getting text from the `webservice APIs`. This is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#4a4a4a"> 

    <!-- Player Header -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <!-- Song Title, here I want to use marquee -->
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/songTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
            android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
            android:paddingRight="15dip"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
            android:focusable="true" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
            android:freezesText="true"/> 

        <!-- Playlist button -->
        <!-- <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnPlaylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_playlist"
            android:background="@null"/> -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Song Thumbnail Image -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/songThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/player_header_bg">

    <ImageView 

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/adele"/>    
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Player Footer -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_footer"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Player Buttons -->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@layout/rounded_corner"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
            <!-- Previous Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPrevious" 
                android:src="@drawable/btn_previous"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Backward Button -->
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/btnBackward"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_backward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Play Button -->
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Forward Button -->
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/btnForward"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_forward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Next Button -->
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Progress Bar/Seek bar -->
    <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
             android:layout_above="@id/player_footer_bg"
             android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler"
             android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
             android:paddingLeft="17dp"
             android:paddingRight="6dp"/>

    <!-- Timer Display -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_above="@id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <!-- Current Duration Label -->
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#eeeeee"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <!-- Total Duration Label -->
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#04cbde"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Repeat / Shuffle buttons -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/timerDisplay"
        android:gravity="center">
        <!-- Repeat Button -->
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnRepeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_repeat"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <!-- Shuffle Button -->        
        <!--  <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnShuffle" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_shuffle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@null"/> -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> This is my Activity,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);

GENRE = getIntent().getExtras().getString("genre");

        songTitleLabel.setSelected(true);
        songTitleLabel.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END); 
        songTitleLabel.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        songTitleLabel.setText(GENRE);
        songTitleLabel.setSingleLine(true);
```

> But it is not working. Please help me to find out what I am missing here.

Comment: can you please post your marquee string how it will look like, a sample.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan , sir, It is the name of selected song and I am getting it from API. it is simply a song name like "Love Story" or "In The End"

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan, I have tried it with Static string, once I put it in xml using android:text="Lorem Ipsum Dummy Text. Lorem Ipsum Dummy Text"....... and once in java using  songTitleLabel.setText("Lorem Ipsum Dummy Text. Lorem Ipsum Dummy Text"); but the result was same everytime

Comment: Actually marquee will work fine for lengthy string and not for the small strings.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan So what is the accurate length could be supported by Marquee??? any approximation so I will try to limit my string

Comment: it should be greater than the length of device screen width or you need to fix the width less than that of length of the incoming string

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan thank you sir for pointing out such a important thing. basically no one even think about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102470/discussion-between-devraj-and-ragu-swaminathan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted the answer for what i mentioned in the comment.

Though the code you wrote for implementing the Marquee is fine and correct, we need to mind that,

> The text, that will be shown should be greater than the length of the
>   device screen width or need to fix the width less than the length
>   of the incoming string, whether it may be static or dynamic text.

Thank you for mentioning, @devraj.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

**Xml file**

Just replace your textview like this, I have removed some unusual tags and it works for me.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:paddingRight="15dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

**Java class**

```
package com.example.demoproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
        private TextView songTitleLabel;
        
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            
            songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
            songTitleLabel.setSelected(true);
            songTitleLabel.setText("LOREM IPSUM DUMMY TEXT. LOREM IPSUM DUMMY TEXTLOREM IPSUM DUMMY TEXT. LOREM IPSUM DUMMY TEXTLOREM IPSUM DUMMY TEXT.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to mention it as an perfect answer.I have seen many
>   posts  regarding this but didn't find the exact answer for the
>   particular situation where I am full filling all the condition
>   required for marquee . I got the correct answer From the comment of
>   @**Ragu Swaminatha**. ***"The length of the String( you want to use in marquee)
>   should be greater then the width of the device  screen"*** this is the
>   perfect answer. Whether the String is coming from API or it is static.